# Using Skaffold with Java

Tags: java, maven, kubernetes, skaffold

I was testing Skaffod and It is a great tool for microservices development.
But I do not find any tutorial on how to use it with Java. Is there any support to Maven builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion going on about adding [support for Java apps here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/526), you can very much use [Docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) with Skaffold. A probably working example is [available here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/527/files)

Your build portion of Skaffold file will look something like:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1alpha2
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    dateTime:
      format: 2006-01-02_15-04-05.999_MST
      timezone: Local
  artifacts:
  - imageName: <repo>/<image>
    workspace: ./appdir
```

In the `appdir` - you can use a multistage Dockerfile and integrate with rest of the workflow. Multistage Dockefile will build artefact in one stage and create a container using the artefact of the first stage.

Answer (score 1):

Skaffold now supports JIB out of the box which will be more efficient than multistage Dockerfile building! Check out the [JIB Maven example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/jib) in Skaffold.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but alternatively now it allows you to specify a custom build script: [Custom Build Script](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/custom/)

I'm assuming you could try as below, or source a `build.sh` as their documentation exemplifies.

```yaml
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: my-image
    custom:
      buildCommand: mvn package && docker build .
```